# Geometry node model becomes white after converting it to mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was trying to get the procedural building demo of geometry nodes to convert into mesh so that I can export it as a fbx for my game but when I apply the geometry node it becomes white

Here's a video in the reddit post showing the problem:
https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ohx3jn/geometry_node_model_becomes_white_after/

Comment: Some of your base meshes might have flipped normals or more than one material assigned to them.

Comment: @metaphor_set: did you try to apply geomode modifier? i could reproduce his behaviour...

Comment: @Chris - Last time I tried, it worked as expected, albeit on a simpler object and also not with Blender 2.92.1. If it's a reproducable problem, it's probably a bug and should be reported [on the official bug tracker](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports)

Comment: I have a feeling this is due to the objects being instanced.  They don't have their own real UV or materials; the instancing object probably doesn't even link the mats used.  Right now, in 2.93, this is probably just a fact of life for instanced GN meshes.  It is part of something that is already being worked on, because there are a whole horde of problems associated with this (instanced attributes being unavailable, further modifiers destroying instanced UV, etc.)  But I can't say what we'll end up with in the end.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.